# Angular 6: Custom validators not executing

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I've been fighting this for 2 days now. I just can't figure out what is wrong. It seems that my custom validators are not executed.

If you just press the 'Next' button every control is highlighted with red borders. If you fill the form, type different values in the email fields and press 'Next' the form is valid and I don't see any of the console.log's from the custom email validator.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwhgpb

Comment: Sorry... This is my first stackblitz and I don't know how to add it properly... maybe someone can enlighten me....

Comment: Anyone let me know, Where I can see the code?

Comment: I edited the url to stackblitz... this one should be the editor url.

Comment: For email use `input type="email"`.

Comment: Thanks @ChatarSIngh ... Fixed it :-)

Comment: Only add the this.emailValidator to the second email, this code does not need to be executed twice. Does not fix the not firing issue but better practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (IF you want to excute passwordValidator you need to add '()' to your Validator Function example **password1: new
>   FormControl("",[Validators.required,this.passwordValidator()]),** Even
>   though it will throw error because FormGroup you used inside
>   will not have a reference to the formData password1 and password2)

If you want to compare two input field you need to use formGroup inside formGroup because if you do not use form group for the formGroup will not hold object like this.

```
value: Object
email1: "data"
email2: ""
__proto__: Object
```

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators Use This Ref for Implement ComparePassword and Email

```
/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
```

Comment: Thanks! You guided me down the right path :-D ... I have edited my stackblitz code, and it works like a charm.
Should I include the final solution in my question... Is that good practice?

Comment: @Chellappan saved my day

Comment: I always forget this and kill like two hrs everytime

Answer (score 0):

> Use `type="email"` instead of `type="text"` in your input field unless the `formgroup` object does not know the field values is valid or not.

Check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eol5eq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This does not work, try email: a@a and repeat email: ab@a -> data valid.

Comment: You probably misunderstood my comment.. I fixed the email type, but this does not fix the issue. Email and password validators is still not executed...